# Android target: not installed in Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I want to install Android SDK and Cordova if run this

```
$cordova requirements
```

I have the same problem

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
android: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/AvdManagerCli : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

I searched for the Error but I can't find a good solution and most answers are for Windows or mac but not for Linux

```
sdk = /home/myland/Documents/tools
platform-tools = /home/myland/Documents/tools/platform-tools
```

what can I do about the problem?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: thank you i am very sorry i don't konw about this

Answer (score -1):

if any body get the error in linux can do the
step one 
download last Android stdio , JDK lasts  and NodeJs with install cordova

```
npm install -g cordova --save
```

step two

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
/home/user/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

if install download in folder home
thank you

Answer (score -2):

i update java to version 8 and install Gradle and make AVD android 
now good

```
# cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
```